# How to install packages for python 2.7 when pip defaults to python 3.8 on Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am working on the Ubuntu terminal and I have both python 3.8 and 2.7 installed. I have changed the default to use the 2.7 version. However, when I run `pip -V` this is what it says:
`pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`
So any installations I do using pip will go to the 3.8 version. What do I do to have pip install to the 2.7 version?

Comment: try python -m pip where python is the desired version

Comment: just do `pip2` or `pip2.7` to use pip for python 2.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+Python+version